# Rgd Subdomain File not Found

Tags: html, subdomain, cpanel

Rgd Subdomain File not Found

I using cpanel/whm to add my subdomain

E.g

```
picture.mydomain.com
```

Then there a folder /picture in my www folder

I put readme.html in /www/picture

I type

picture.mydomain.com/readme.html

but the file return not found.

What should I do to make it accessible.